# How to fix this query to avoid syntax error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to fix this query because SQL Server throws a syntax error.

The purpose of the query is concatenate the column `Articulo.ReferenciaFichas` into one string to be included in a `select` statement.

**Tables**

Articulos:

```
        Codigo    Nombre           
        ---------------
        Z540021   Motul oil 1050w2
        Z540022   Motul oil 1030w
```

ReferenciaFichas:

```
       Codigo      Articulo
       --------------------           
       MF99.00102   Z540021
       MP08-0186    Z540021
       OUT1006      Z540021
       MTUL14       Z540022
```

To concatenate the column, I wrote this standalone query that works

```
DECLARE @provrefs VARCHAR(200)

SELECT 
    @provrefs = COALESCE(@provrefs + ',', '') + [provlist].[Codigo]
FROM
    (SELECT
         [Codigo]
     FROM 
         [GES16100].[dbo].[ReferenciasFichas]
     WHERE 
         Articulo = 'Z540021') provlist

SELECT @provrefs
```

Result is:

```
MF99.00102,MP08-0186,OUT1006
```

But when I move this query to a select, the query not works due syntax error.
I have tried moving the declare statement at the top of the file, and added
extra parentheses. But I could not find any solution.

How I can fix this ?

This query is not working:

```
SELECT
    [arts].[Codigo] AS [Referencia],
    ((DECLARE @provrefs VARCHAR(200)            
      SELECT @provrefs = COALESCE(@provrefs + ',', '') + [provlist].[Codigo]
      FROM
          (SELECT [reff].[Codigo]
           FROM [GES16100].[dbo].[ReferenciasFichas] reff
           WHERE [reff].[Articulo] = [arts].[Codigo]) provlist)
SELECT @provrefs) AS [Proveedores]
FROM [GES16100].[dbo].[Articulos] AS arts
```

Expected results

```
Referencia    Proveedores
--------------------------
Z540021       MF99.00102,MP08-0186,OUT1006
Z540022       MTUL14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
select 
    Referencia = arts.Codigo
  , Proveedores = stuff(
      (
      select ','+reff.Codigo
      from GES16100.dbo.ReferenciasFichas as reff
      where reff.Articulo = arts.Codigo
      for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'')
from GES16100.dbo.Articulos as arts
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MVSW22706

returns:

```
+------------+------------------------------+
| Referencia |         Proveedores          |
+------------+------------------------------+
| Z540021    | MF99.00102,MP08-0186,OUT1006 |
| Z540022    | MTUL14                       |
+------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried for xml path, but I don't know how to remove the first comma. Thanks also for the stuff reference.